# Changing a header upon user login

Tags: javascript, php

I did search through this website nothing came up to actually answering my question. If someone did give an answer it was really short, understated, and or poorly written. I had also looked around on the internet, a majority of the articles or, "tutorials" were based around WordPress.

I am using Bootstrap, my own custom CSS, HTML, JavaScript, and PHP. Basically, I have a header in a Include folder and to the right I have the links as options of: 'Signup', 'Login', and 'Logout'. When a user logs in I would like the header to change those options to something like: 'Profile', 'Edit Profile', and 'Logout'.

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="EN">

        <head>

            <title> <?php echo $pageTitle; ?> </title>

            <!--Universal Encoding for HTML5-->
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />

            <!--Making it mobile friendly-->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

            <!--Bootstrap's CDN-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="CSS/custom.css" />

            <!--Needed JavaScript Files-->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <!--Custom Implementations -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/typeWriter.js"></script> <!-- Gives our Quote or Important Message -->

        </head>

        <body>

            <!--Header-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="navbar-header">

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"> Vomica </a>

                    </div>

                    <div>

                        <!--Left-->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            <li class="<?php if($section == "home") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="index.php"> Home </a> </li>
                            <li class="<?php if($section == "buy") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="buy.php"> Buy </a> </li>
                            <li class="<?php if($section == "sell") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="sell.php"> Sell </a> </li>

                        </ul>

                        <!--Menu Items on the Right-->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                            <li class="<?php if($section == "signing") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="register.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span> Sign Up </a> </li>
                            <li class="<?php if($section == "logs") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="login.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> </span> Login </a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="logout.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </span> Logout </a> </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    <!--Our Quote and or Imortant Message-->
                    <div id="box" class="text-center typeWriter"></div>

                </div>

            </nav>
```

Could someone please answer this question with examples and detail I couldn't find nothing else on the internet pertaining to this topic. I'd prefer to do the connection in PHP but, if need be JavaScript will be acceptable.

Comment: Is someone going to help?